# Empty Array of Array

Tags: arrays, string, dictionary

**Swift Xcode version 13.2.1**

Here, I have array of string **var ActiveJobDic: [[String: Any]] = []** ,how to declare that this array is empty! I have simply empty this array as following ,This does not work!

```
if ActiveJobDic == []{
print("working")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how to declare that this array ***is empty***.

Your question contains the answer. There is `isEmpty`

And please name variables with starting lowercase letter

```
var activeJobDic: [[String: Any]] = [] // actually activeJobArray

if activeJobDic.isEmpty {
    print("working")
}
```

Comment: working Fine! Thanks for your Answer